# Issues with code in overriden abstract method in Java enum

Tags: java, enums, abstract

I'm trying to implement an abstract method in an enum as in code below, but Eclipse is underlining the .getUrls method and displaying the tooltip "this method requires a body instead of a semicolon, two quick fixes: (add body, add 'abstract' modifier)", none of which make sense to me.

The method itself is just a normal method that works in other classes.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
public enum Site {
    PORTAL1 ("http://www.somedomain.net") {
        @Override
        public void method() {
            ArrayList<String> urlList = urlManager.getUrls(int number);
        }
    };
    // more values

    public abstract void method();
    private final String baseUrl;
    private UrlManager urlManager;

    private Site(final String baseUrl) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        urlManager = new UrlManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the `int` doing there in front of `number`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that the following line is not syntactically valid:

```
ArrayList<String> urlList = urlManager.getUrls(int number);
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^ HERE
```

Another problem is that you can't access non-`static` members of `Site` from `PORTAL1`. You either need to make `UrlManager` `static`, or have every `Site` subclass have its own instance of `UrlManager`.

Comment: That is not the only problem.

Comment: It's the one causing the error being asked about, though... :)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the obvious problem with `int number`, you can't reference `urlManager` from an enum instance. You could make it protected so it can be accessed from each instance:

```
public enum Site {

    PORTAL1("http://www.somedomain.net") {
        @Override
        public void method() {
            ArrayList<String> urlList = urlManager.getUrls(5);
        }
    };
    // more values

    public abstract void method();
    private final String baseUrl;
    protected UrlManager urlManager;

    private Site(final String baseUrl) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        urlManager = new UrlManager();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the enum class is not declared abstract, and probably even not wanted to be called abstract, do:

```
public void method() {
    }
```

A non-abstract class cannot have an abstract method.

Answer (score 0):

You have some incorrect syntax going on:

```
urlManager.getUrls(int number);
```

You are kind of declaring a variable where you should be passing an argument. Also, where is `urlManager` declared?